# Can I paste RTF text from a RichTextBox to a WebBrowser Control?

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control, richtextbox, copy-paste, rtf

I'm trying to copy formatted text from a RichTextBox control into a WebBrowser control and retain it's formatting. From there I'd like to grab the DocumentText in HTML format to save into a database. I've tried using methods on the RichTextBox like .SelectAll() and .Copy() and then doing a Document.ExecCommand("paste", False, Nothing) on the WebBrowser control but it doesn't paste anything. I've also tried Clipboard.SetText(RichTextBox1.Rtf) and then that doesn't work either...

My ultimate goal here is taking the formatted text from the RichTextBox and saving it into a database as HTML since it appears Microsoft's Client Side Reporting doesn't support RichText (even though I read that it did), but does have limited HTML support.

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me: use Office Interop, create a Word file, copy and paste into this file and then save as html.